# How to get minimum radius location

Tags: mysql, join, geocoding

I have 2 tables

```
1. feeds => id,name
2. feed_locations => id, feed_id, latitude,longitude,location_name
```

A feed have multiple locations. 
now i want to search near by feed from user current location 
I require user latitude or longitude so i fetch from google location and radius 
Now i use this mysql query

```
SELECT 
    `Feed`.`id`, 
    `Feed`.`name`, 
    (3959 * acos (cos ( radians(40.7127837) ) * cos( radians( FeedLocation.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( FeedLocation.longitude ) - radians(-74.00594130000002) ) + sin ( radians(40.7127837) ) * sin( radians( FeedLocation.latitude )))) AS `distance`, 
    (Select COUNT(id) FROM feed_locations WHERE feed_id = `Feed`.`id`) AS `location_count` FROM `feeds` AS `Feed` 
    LEFT JOIN `feed_locations` AS `FeedLocation` ON (`FeedLocation`.`feed_id` = `Feed`.`id`) 
    GROUP BY `Feed`.`id` HAVING distance < 10 
    ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

This query giving me result but 
i require minimum distance of the feed_locations from user current location. Distance field give me highest value but i require lowest value from feed_locations table.

 
My query is working but issue it that :
Like if a single feed have 10 location lik 1m,2m,3m,4m,5m,10m,100m distance. and i want to find 5m distance all feed then it works but it shows me that this feed have 5m. distance from me but result should be 1m distance.

I have created a Fiddle please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c408e6/5

 According to the fiddle in table 1 result is coming that feed1 is 4.02m from my current location but this feed have 2 location in table2 i have show each of location distance .so feed1 one of location is zero mile distance from me but it give result that feed1 is 4.02mile

Comment: i will update tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
a.id,
a.name,
a.distance,
a.location_count
FROM
  (SELECT
    `Feed`.`id`, 
    `Feed`.`name`, 
    (3959 * acos (cos ( radians(40.7127837) ) * 
    cos( radians( FeedLocation.latitude ) ) * 
    cos( radians( FeedLocation.longitude ) -
    radians(-74.00594130000002) ) + sin ( radians(40.7127837) ) * 
    sin( radians( FeedLocation.latitude )))) AS `distance`, 
      (Select COUNT(id) 
         FROM feed_locations 
         WHERE feed_id = `Feed`.`id`) AS `location_count` 
         FROM `feeds` AS `Feed` 
         LEFT JOIN `feed_locations` AS `FeedLocation` ON (`FeedLocation`.`feed_id` = `Feed`.`id`) 
    ORDER BY `distance` ASC) AS a
    GROUP BY a.id HAVING distance < 10;
```

In the fiddle I worked out this query you see and it works, now result is 0. The point is that if you group a not ordered set of records and then you order... you do not order anything. You have to order and then group the ordered set.

Hope it works for you.

Regards

Comment: My query is working but issue it that :

Like if a single feed have 10 location lik 1m,2m,3m,4m,5m,10m,100m distance. and i want to find 5m distance all feed then it works but it shows me that this feed have 5m. distance from me but result should be 1m distance.

Comment: when we execute the first query then distance must be 0 not 4.02

Comment: I do not understand your point. Distance is calculated for very locations in first query then locations are ordered by distance and you have the closest for each group plus the number of locations in that group.

Comment: Just saw it... I check

Comment: no no try to understand in my first query i show how records are coming for me . that is wrong because we have 2 location in Newyork for a single feed under 10m.Ok . now it not fetching nearest location to me it fetching highest location under 10m. it should be zero mile

Comment: Hi this is work for me in mysql but i want to implement it cakephp. i have ask another question plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169673/select-in-select-query-cakephp