# Select in select query cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have 2 table

```
   1. feeds => id,name
   2. feed_locations => id, feed_id, latitude,longitude,location_name
```

This is my cakephp code

```
    $radious    =   '10';
    $this->paginate = array(
        'joins' => array(
            array('table' => 'feed_locations',
                'alias' => 'FeedLocation',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'FeedLocation.feed_id = Feed.id',
                )
            )
        ),
        'limit'      => 10,             
        'fields' => array('id','name','(3959 * acos (cos ( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( FeedLocation.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( FeedLocation.longitude ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin ( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( FeedLocation.latitude )))) AS `distance`'),
        'recursive' => -1,
        'order'    =>  'distance ASC',
        'group' => 'Feed.id HAVING distance <'.$radious          
    );
```

It give me output query as

```
SELECT 
    `Feed`.`id`, 
    `Feed`.`name`, 
    (3959 * acos (cos ( radians(40.7127837) ) * cos( radians( FeedLocation.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( FeedLocation.longitude ) - radians(-74.00594130000002) ) + sin ( radians(40.7127837) ) * sin( radians( FeedLocation.latitude )))) AS `distance`, 
    (Select COUNT(id) FROM feed_locations WHERE feed_id = `Feed`.`id`) AS `location_count` FROM `feeds` AS `Feed` 
    LEFT JOIN `feed_locations` AS `FeedLocation` ON (`FeedLocation`.`feed_id` = `Feed`.`id`) 
    GROUP BY `Feed`.`id` HAVING distance < 10 
    ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

My query is working but issue it that :

Like if a single feed have 10 location like 1m,2m,3m,4m,5m,10m,100m distance. and i want to find 5m distance all feed then it works but it shows me that this feed have 5m. distance from me but result should be 1m distance. 
I want to implement this mysql query in cakephp syntax

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    a.distance,
    a.location_count
    FROM
      (SELECT
        `Feed`.`id`, 
        `Feed`.`name`, 
        (3959 * acos (cos ( radians(40.7127837) ) * 
        cos( radians( FeedLocation.latitude ) ) * 
        cos( radians( FeedLocation.longitude ) -
        radians(-74.00594130000002) ) + sin ( radians(40.7127837) ) * 
        sin( radians( FeedLocation.latitude )))) AS `distance`, 
          (Select COUNT(id) 
             FROM feed_locations 
             WHERE feed_id = `Feed`.`id`) AS `location_count` 
             FROM `feeds` AS `Feed` 
             LEFT JOIN `feed_locations` AS `FeedLocation` ON (`FeedLocation`.`feed_id` = `Feed`.`id`) 
        ORDER BY `distance` ASC) AS a
        GROUP BY a.id HAVING distance < 10;
```

This query give me exact result. please let me know how can i use this query in cakephp

Comment: i am not understanding this type of query how to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code

```
function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page, $recursive, $extra){
    $db         = $this->getDataSource();
    $modelName  =   $this->alias;   
    $result = $db->fetchAll(
        'SELECT 
        '.$modelName.'.id,
        '.$modelName.'.name,
        '.$modelName.'.distance,
        '.$modelName.'.location_count
        FROM
          (SELECT
            `Feed`.`id`, 
            `Feed`.`name`, 
            (3959 * acos (cos ( radians(40.7127837) ) * 
            cos( radians( FeedLocation.latitude ) ) * 
            cos( radians( FeedLocation.longitude ) -
            radians(-74.00594130000002) ) + sin ( radians(40.7127837) ) * 
            sin( radians( FeedLocation.latitude )))) AS `distance`, 
              (Select COUNT(id) 
                 FROM feed_locations 
                 WHERE feed_id = `Feed`.`id`) AS `location_count` 
                 FROM `feeds` AS `Feed` 
                 LEFT JOIN `feed_locations` AS `FeedLocation` ON (`FeedLocation`.`feed_id` = `Feed`.`id`) 
            ORDER BY `distance` ASC) AS '.$modelName.'
            GROUP BY '.$modelName.'.id HAVING distance < 10;'
    );  
    return $result;
}
```

It works perfectly for me.

I have manage this query in model . i create a function paginate in model and mention this query . then it automatic paginate the data.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP you can also use prepared statements, in which you can use SQL to create your queries, check out the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements